# Python 3 - Extract sub-dictionary values from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I have a list of data with 10 elements called DATA.

Each element is a dictionary (DATA[0] is a dictionary, DATA[1] is a dictionary, .. DATA[9] is a dictionary).

Each of these dictionaries has a key called "Date".

**Is there any way I can extract the individual values corresponding from the 'Date' key from each of these 10 dictionaries into their own separate list? 
In the end, my list would be `NEWLIST = {DATA[0]['Date'], DATA[1]['Date'], .... , DATA[9]['Date']).`**

Is there any way to do this without a for loop?

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far with inputs and lets start from there.

Comment: Yes, read about [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 2):

you can try list comprehension:

```py
NEWLIST = [x["date"] for x in DATA]
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be a straightforward list comprehension.
If you're not familiar with that construct, I recommend that you find and work through a tutorial on the topic.

Instead of stepping explicitly through the list, just iterate over the list.

```
new_list = [data_dict['Date'] for data_dict in DATA]
```

Note that I've changed all but the original list name to conform to PEP8 guidelines.